# Wildcards in Nagios hostgroup_name exclusions

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm having difficulty finding good documentation for wildcards and regular expressions (particularly as they work with exclusions) in Nagios.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

In `nagios.cfg`, the following are set, supposedly enabling `*` and `?` as wildcards:

```
use_regexp_matching=1
use_true_regexp_matching=0
```

In `services.cfg`, we have a service that we would like to apply to all but a few objects; that is all Linux hosts, but not load balancers.  Explicit exclusion works:

```
define service {
     use                  generic-service
     service_description  Puppet check
     hostgroup_name       prod, staging, !prod-site_a-lbs
     check_command        check_puppet_alive_nrpe
}
```

But, we have many sites, each with load balancers in their own hostgroups (so notifications can be easily managed by site).  Rather than having a long list of `!prod-site_a-lbs`, `!staging-site_a-lbs`, `!prod-site_b-lbs`. I'd hoped to be able to modify the `hostgroup_name` line to:

```
     hostgroup_name       prod, staging, !*-lbs
```

I have tried this, and while we don't get an error, this service check is still being applied to our load balancers.  To double check, I have also tried:

```
     hostgroup_name        prod, staging, !.*-lbs
```

But, this fails, as expected (since `use_true_regexp_matching` is not set), when running `checkconfig-noprecache`:

```
 Error: Could not find any hostgroup matching '!.*lbs' ...
```

In testing, `.*` is accepted by `checkconfig-noprecache` if `!` is removed.

Is what we're trying possible?  Can we use wildcards to exclude matching hostgroups? Or, is there an alternative that would be just as clean?

---

**Update** (2015-09-21):  After testing Keith's answer, this configuration is working:

In `services.cfg`:

```
define service {
    use                  generic-service
    service_description  Puppet check
    hostgroup_name       prod, staging, !lbs
    check_command        check_puppet_alive_nrpe
}
```

And in `hostgroups.cfg`, I have defined a new hostgroup using a regular expression in the 'members' directive:

```
define hostgroup {
    hostgroup_name  lbs
    alias           Load Balancers
    members         ^lb.*
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I believe you can achieve this is by making a new hostgroup comprised of the hosts in question (using a wildcard), and then excluding this new hostgroup.